# (Oracle) How to get SUM values based on values in other columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose there is data like below:

```
ID   Name  Cost  
ID1    A    10    
ID1    A    60    
ID1    B    20
ID1    C    20
ID2    B    10
ID2    B    50
ID2    C    50
ID3    B     5
```

Here in the table above, ID and NAME are not unique.
And I want to get SUM values based on NAME, so the expected result is like below:

```
 ID   A_Costs  B_Costs  C_Costs  AB_Costs
 ID1    70       20       20       90
 ID2             60       50       60
 ID3             5                 5
```

A_Cost, B_Costs, and C_Costs are costs when the name is A, B or C.
But what do I do if I want to get costs when the name is A and B?
So what I was trying to do was this:

```
Select t2.ID,
SUM(DECODE (t2.name, 'A', t2.Cost, null)),
SUM(DECODE (t2.name, 'B', t2.Cost, null))
--(select sum(t1.cost) from table t1. where t1.name in ('A','B') and t1.id = t2.id)
from table t2
group by t2.id
```

But this does not work.
How do I get the costs when the name is A and B like the line I commented out? Is there any effective way to get the value like that in one query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `decode()`, you can do:

```
sum(decode(t2.name, 'A', t2.cost, 'B' t2.cost))
```

Or you can use a `case` statement:

```
sum(case when t2.name in ('A', 'B') then t2.cost end)
```

Full query:

```
select id,
       sum(case when name = 'A' then cost end) as a_costs,
       sum(case when name = 'B' then cost end) as b_costs,
       sum(case when name = 'C' then cost end) as c_costs,
       sum(case when name IN ('A', 'B') then cost end) as ab_costs
  from SomeTable
 group by id 
 order by id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9d22/2)

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to aggregate after using `sum` in the inner query.

```
select 
id, max(a_cost) as A_Costs,  max(b_cost) as B_Costs,
max(c_cost) as C_Costs, nvl(max(a_cost),0) + nvl(max(b_cost),0) as AB_Costs
from (
select ID,
sum(case when name = 'A' then cost end) as a_cost,
sum(case when name = 'B' then cost end) as b_cost,
sum(case when name = 'C' then cost end) as c_cost
from table
group by id 
) t 
group by id
```